# SQL/Snowflake - Add rows of future dates and populate with last value from another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 4 columns, "DateByQuarter","FromCurrency","ToCurrency","Rate" - this is in one table. The final "DateByQuarter" value is "2021-09-30", and this dataset updates every end of quarter (e.g. the next set of currency pairs will be uploaded on 2021-12-31)

My aim is to create a new table where I can dynamically add 7 years' worth of quarters in the rows below this original table, and populate it with the last available currency rates. For example since 2021-09-30 is the last date here, all the currency rates for the next 7 years will be based off this.

So far I can't find an easy way to do this, any help is greatly appreciated!

->Added a sample of the table below; 2021-12-31 onwards takes rates for all currency pairs from 2021-09-30.

| DatebyQuarter | FromCurrency | ToCurrency | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2021-03-31 | USD | INR | 74.27 |
| 2021-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.24 |
| 2021-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.86 |
| 2021-06-30 | USD | EUR | 74.32 |
| 2021-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.22 |
| 2021-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2021-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2021-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2021-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2021-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2021-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2022-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2022-03-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2022-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2022-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2022-06-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2022-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2022-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2022-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2022-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2022-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2022-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2022-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2023-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2023-03-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2023-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2023-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2023-06-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2023-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2023-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2023-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2023-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2023-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2023-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2023-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2024-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2024-03-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2024-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2024-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2024-06-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2024-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2024-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2024-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2024-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2024-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2024-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2024-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2025-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2025-03-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2025-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2025-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2025-06-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2025-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2025-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2025-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2025-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2025-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2025-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2025-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2026-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2026-03-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2026-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2026-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2026-06-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2026-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2026-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2026-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2026-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2026-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2026-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2026-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2027-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2027-03-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2027-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2027-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2027-06-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2027-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2027-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2027-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2027-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2027-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2027-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2027-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2028-03-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2028-03-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2028-03-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2028-06-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2028-06-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2028-06-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2028-09-30 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2028-09-30 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2028-09-30 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |
| 2028-12-31 | USD | EUR | 0.85 |
| 2028-12-31 | USD | EUR | 73.09 |
| 2028-12-31 | USD | CAD | 1.26 |

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired results

Comment: Are the values in column DateByQuarter always the last date of the quarter? Do you generate data for the past 7 years or for the future 7 years? Like Felipe mentioned, sample data and expected outputs could be useful to clarify things.

Comment: Thanks Felipe and Eric! Included a sample data/desired results. Idea here is to append future rates to the same table. To Eric's question, yes the last date of each quarter is in the DateByQuarter column, with data generated for the future 7 years.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach and I was able to assign the last rate to all the future quarters in the SELECT statement, you can use the same approach to update  the table.

```
create table  cur_rate (qat_end date, src_cur varchar2(5), tgt_cur varchar2(5), rate number(6,3));

SELECT CUR_ALL.*, LST_RT.* FROM cur_rate CUR_ALL
JOIN (select qat_end, src_cur, tgt_cur, rate 
    from cur_rate
    where rate is not null
    qualify row_number() over (partition by TGT_CUR order by QAT_END desc) = 1
      ) LST_RT ON LST_RT.tgt_CUR = CUR_ALL.tgt_CUr
      -- you can add other column in the join condition LST_RT.src_cur = cur_all.src_cur =  also 
      ;
```